# ant build to stop tomcat server

Tags: ant

I am trying to stop tomcat with the below code,

```
 <target name="tomcat-stop" if="tomcat.running" depends="check-port" >
  <echo message="Tomcat is running...stopping it"/> 
     <java jar="${tomcat.home}/bin/bootstrap.jar" fork="true" >
         <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=${tomcat.home}"/>
         <arg line="stop"/>
     </java>
 </target>
```

.

It returns the error

> "[java] Error: Unable to access jarfile 10.50.255.250:\home\Deploymenttest\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\bin\bootstrap.jar
>        [java] Java Result: 1"

Comment: As far as I can see that error message cannot be a result of executing the target you are showing. Is there another target in which you actually try to execute the server stop?

Comment: sry wrongly updated the target. Please find the updated stop target

Answer (score 0):

I tried in this way and it works,

```
<target name="tomcat-stop" depends="check-port">
 <sshexec host="10.0.60.0"
    trust="true"
  username="${server_username}"
  password="${server_password}"
 command="sh /home/Deploymenttest/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/shutdown.sh" />
  <!--command="cd /home/Deploymenttest/ rm -rf test"/>-->
   </target>
```